# Need help understanding DNSfilter script

Tags: dns

I was doing some searching on Github and came across this particular script, and was wondering if anyone could maybe help explain what this script technically does?  I've been doing a lot of research on DNS filtering and am trying to get a better understanding of what DNS filtering actually IS, and how people can abuse it. Here is the script in question:

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Pcap;
use Net::Pcap::Easy;

if ( $#ARGV != 2 ) {
    print "Usage: perl filter.pl <outputfile> <minbytereply> <domain>\n";
    print " Example: perl filter.pl output.txt 3000 1x1.cz\n";
    print " Coded by Vypor, https://github.com/Vypor\n";
    exit(1);
}

my $err;
my $minbytes = $ARGV[1];
my $domain = $ARGV[2];

my $interface = pcap_lookupdev( \$err );
my $ethip = `/sbin/ifconfig $interface | grep "inet addr" | awk -F: '{print \$2}' | awk '{print \$1}'`;
$ethip = substr( $ethip, 0, -1 );

# all arguments to new are optoinal
my $npe = Net::Pcap::Easy->new(
    dev              => $interface,
    filter           => "not src host $ethip and port 53 and greater $minbytes",
    packets_per_loop => 10,
    bytes_to_capture => 1024,
    timeout_in_ms    => 0, # 0ms means forever
    promiscuous      => 0, # true or false

        udp_callback => sub {
        my ($npe, $ether, $ip, $udp, $header ) = @_;
        my $xmit = `date +"%H:%M:%S"`;
        chomp($xmit);
        print "$xmit $ip->{src_ip} -> $ip->{dest_ip} $udp->{len}\n";

        open (FFILE, ">>$ARGV[0]");
        print FFILE "$ip->{src_ip} $domain $udp->{len}\n";
        close FFILE;
},
);

1 while $npe->loop;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a badly written Perl script that seems intended to snoop network traffic and write a log of all incoming DNS packets. Why it's called "filter" you'll have to ask whoever wrote it.

Please do not use this script as an example of how to write Perl. The lines were the author calls out to external programs to filter text and a format a date are huge red flags that he had little knowledge of Perl, and the line with one `grep` and two `awk` on it shows that he didn't know much about `awk` or shell programming either. And on top of that, most of the script is cut-n-pasted from the documentation for the `Net::Pcap::Easy` module (including the one comment there is).